# How to delete line from the screen?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of lines.

```
var arrayOfLine : [(line: CAShapeLayer, linePath: UIBezierPath, 
point1 : CGPoint, point2 : CGPoint)] = 
[(CAShapeLayer(), UIBezierPath(), CGPoint.zero, CGPoint.zero), 
(CAShapeLayer(), UIBezierPath(), CGPoint.zero, CGPoint.zero),
(CAShapeLayer(), UIBezierPath(), CGPoint.zero, CGPoint.zero)]
```

This is how I draw one of the lines.

```
func drawing(index : Int)
{
    if index == 0
    {
        arrayOfLine[0].point1 = CGPoint(x: 40, y: self.view.frame.height/2)
        arrayOfLine[0].point2 = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - 40, y: self.view.frame.height/2)

        arrayOfLine[0].linePath.move(to: arrayOfLine[0].point1)
        arrayOfLine[0].linePath.addLine(to: arrayOfLine[0].point2)
        arrayOfLine[0].line.path = arrayOfLine[0].linePath.cgPath

        arrayOfLine[0].line.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        arrayOfLine[0].line.lineWidth = 1
        arrayOfLine[0].line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(arrayOfLine[0].line)
    }
}
```

I want to remove one line, but it doesn't dissapeaar from the screen. What do I need to to?

```
arrayOfLine.remove(at: 0)
```

[image: Lines]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You posted code that sets up an array of tuples, and then other code that configures the first entry in that array, and adds it's shape layer as a sublayer of your view's layer. If you want to remove a layer you would have to index into your array of tuples, fetch the layer, and then remove that layer from your view's layer:

```
func removeLayerAtIndex(_ index: Int) {
  guard  index < arrayOfLine.count else { return }

  arrayOfLine[index].line.removeFromSuperLayer()
}
```